# Check if exist decorator on property

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a way to check if property has some decorator?

There is a way to do like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"
       [required]='model.decorator["required"]'      [minlength]='=model.decorator["minlength"]?.value' maxlength="24"
       name="name" [(ngModel)]="hero.name"
       #name="ngModel" >
```